# Apache django not saving image with image field in form

Tags: python, django, apache, image-uploading

I have a form which is working fine if I don't add any image, but it gives template not found error as per the apache log if I try to upload image. The problem here is that my form with image is working fine on my local server (django) but not uploading the image when I start apache and run the project in it.

This is my .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/anmol/suvidha.wsgi

ServerName suvidha.com
Alias /static /var/www/suvidha/register/static/

<Directory /var/www/suvidha/>
Order allow,deny  
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My .wsgi file

```
import os
import sys
sys.path = ['/var/www/suvidha'] + sys.path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'suvidha.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

My .settings file

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = join(BASE_DIR, 'register/static')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/static/images/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
 )
```

My directories listing

```
/var
  /www
    /suvidha
      /register
         /static
```

Log file

```
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196] mod_wsgi (pid=15679):Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/byld/suvidha.wsgi'.
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]     return callback(request, **param_dict)
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 32, in server_error
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]     t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 145, in get_template
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196]     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
[Tue Apr 22 00:23:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.58.196] TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

It would be great if someone can help, I am stuck on this and can't find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

What this is telling you is that you have an exception somewhere triggered by the image upload, which would normally result in a 500 error response - but you have no 500.html template to use to display the response. Create the relevant template, and you'll be able to see the real bug.